# Groovy .& closure (method pointer operator) vs {} closure - MethodMissingException

Tags: groovy, closures

I am new to Groovy and I am experimenting with Closures and the `.&` method pointer operator.

In an attempt to learn more about how Groovy works, I set up the following example.

I expected all 3 versions of `isString` to return `true` - however `isString3` throws a `MethodMissingException` and I am not sure that I understand what the actual difference is between `isString2` and `isString3` that is causing the exception.

```
string = 'foo'
isString = {it instanceof String}
println isString(string) // true

// let's try it a different way
isString2 = {String.isInstance(it)}
println isString2(string) // true

// let's try using .& for fancy FP eta reduction
isString3 = String.&isInstance
println isString3(string) // MethodMissingException

// ^^^ No signature of method: java.lang.String.isInstance()
// is applicable for argument types: 
// (java.lang.String) values: [foo]

// EDIT: Case #4
// what if we try a method we know does not exist?
isNotString = String.&isNotInstance
println isNotString(string) // MethodMissingException
// ^^^ gives the same error!

// EDIT: Case #5
// Maybe I am misunderstanding how the .& operator works - let's try an example

bar = 'bar'
equalsBar = bar.&equals
println equalsBar('bar') // true - same as 'bar'.equals('bar')
println equalsBar('baz') // false - same as 'bar'.equals('baz')
// the .& operator has worked as expected in this case
```

I tried searching around SO for other answers but did not really find one that explained the actual difference that I am seeing here.

Comment: `def tmp = java.lang.String.&isInstance`

Comment: @DaveNewton making that change does not appear to change the behavior I am seeing.

Comment: It's sporadic for me and I'm not sure why--I'll show my groovysh output in an answer for formatting sake.

Comment: `isInstance` is coming "Class" class and `equals` coming from Object class.  May be there some difference there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you encounter is caused by the usage of `String` as type and class. In *Java* `String.class` would be the class while `String` is used for the type. The `isInstance` method is defined as `Class<String>.isInstance()` while `.&` tries to access it as a (static) method as `String.isInstance()`. Thus the error

> No signature of method: `java.lang.String.isInstance()`

The closure doesn't look for `java.lang.String.class.isInstance()`, which would work. I couldn't find a way to acually return this method with `.&isInstance` and return `true` for a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

(Not an answer.)

```
groovy:000> def tmp = java.lang.String.&isInstance
===> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@92031aba
groovy:000> tmp('hi')
===> true
```

Cool.

```
groovy:000> def tmp2 = String.&isInstance
===> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@99643448
groovy:000> tmp2('hi')
No signature of method: groovysh_evaluate.tmp2() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [hi]
Possible solutions: dump(), wait(), run(), run(), find(), any()
```

Wat...

```
groovy:000> String
===> class java.lang.String
groovy:000> def tmp = String.&isInstance
===> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@4b3e238d
groovy:000> tmp('hi')
===> true
```

Cool.

```
groovy:000> def tmp2 = String.&isInstance
===> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@3fdea076
groovy:000> tmp2('hi')
No signature of method: groovysh_evaluate.tmp2() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [hi]
Possible solutions: dump(), wait(), run(), run(), find(), any()
groovy:000> def wat = String.&isInstance
===> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure@e3cc658a
groovy:000> wat('hi')
No signature of method: groovysh_evaluate.wat() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [hi]
Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), wait(long, int), with(groovy.lang.Closure), run(), run()
```

Oooookay.

Comment: Sometimes I have issues in `groovysh` if I am using `def` - you might retry the examples without it. I think anything using `def` is scoped to the single command you issue, and once the command has run, the `def` var goes back out of scope. Which is why you see `no signature of ... tmp2()` instead of `no signature of ... isInstance()`

Comment: You can also use `groovyConsole` from the command line if you have it installed, or you can try using https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/ for something that just works with no install/config :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing my code to the following works:

```
isString = String.&invokeMethod.curry('isInstance')
isString('foo') // true
// ^ calling isString('foo') is equivalent to calling
// String.invokeMethod('isInstance', 'foo')
isString.class // CurriedClosure
isString instanceof Closure // true
```

I believe something about trying to make the closure from the `String` class is what is causing the issue, but I do not know for sure.

I would love if someone could post an answer explaining things in detail!